# Django Optimisation of a queryset with Q objects

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset, django-q

I'm using Django 1.8.

I have a queryset that requires a logical "or" and an "and".
It gives :

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    Q(start__gt=today) | Q(end__lte=today),
    active=True).update(active=False)
```

As you may understand it, it should take every active MyModel instances which shouldn't have already started, and the one that have finished, and deactivate them.

"start" and "end" are DateFields, and "active" is a boolean.

It works, but it generates a query that is far from being optimised. I'd like to be able to start the query by filtering on "active" state, then check the other two fields, because in my database, I have thousands of entries, but only few of them have active=True. I would say that this boolean test is faster than the comparisons.

I can't reorder the arguments, because the former with the two Q() is a positioned argument while the latter is a name argument, and I can't chain multiple filter() because it generates an "or", and not an "and".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with adding appropriate indexes?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking (either because I'm quite new to Django, or beacuse I'm not a native english speaker)

Comment: It's not a Django thing, it's a database thing.

Comment: Reference for `db_index`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#db-index

Comment: I thought the indexes were a good thing to use in such a case, because it accelerated the execution, but i didn't think it would change the way the query is executed.
I already have an index on this field.

Comment: I highly doubt the order of lookups has any effect after the query has been run through the query optimizer of your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the SQL command generated by the Django ORM probably won't have the condition clauses in the same order as your `.filter` methods.  So don't worry about the "optimal" order.

Second, no matter in which order the clauses appear in the SQL command, the DB engine will optimize the request and generate an execution plan tailored to your data distribution.  Any DB engine worth considering keeps some data distribution statistics.  If the proportion of `active` records is actually the best discriminant in this query, then it will be filtered first.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about that! I'm quite new to Django, but I've used some db engines for a while, mostly in php, and it seems that I've lost a lot of time trying to optimize my queries in a way that doesn't really matter at the end! At least I'll know it for the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by [chaining filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters)

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    active=True
).filter(
    Q(start__gt=today) | Q(end__lte=today)
).update(active=False)
```

---

### Additional notes

I don't think you'll get any performance gain by first filtering `active` and then filtering `start` and `end`. Because chaning or *not*-chaining will perform the same query. Here's an example from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude):

> ```
> Entry.objects.exclude(pub_date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 3), headline='Hello')
> ```
>
> In SQL terms, that evaluates to:
>
> ```
> SELECT ...
> WHERE NOT (pub_date > '2005-1-3' AND headline = 'Hello')
> ```

Note that the filters have been chained in the example above, yet in the SQL query both the filters are taken together.

**To boost DB performance**

1. Look up DB indexing (as pointed in comments).
2. Considering caching database in memory (see [Memcached](http://memcached.org/), for instance).

Comment: I'll definitely will take a look at memcached for my production server. Thanks for your answer and your advices.